# Binding an integer variable to a real variable through a linear constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Suppose we have a problem where there is a variable $v\in R$ such that $v\ge 0$ and a variable $y\in Z$ such that $y\in \{0,1\}$.

I want to set up a linear restriction such that $y=1$ iff $v>0$.

How can I do that?

---

Half hearted attempt:

If we have an additional constraint that $v < M$ for some constant $M$, then we can set up the two following constraints:

1. $\frac{v}{M} - y \le 0$
2. $y - v < 1$

These constraints are not exactly what I am looking for because a) $v$ is not upper bounded in my problem and b) I cannot use integer programming techniques when there are strict equalities involved.

Hopefully this illustrates what I am after though.

Comment: And in which case is $y=0$ ?

Comment: @callculus $y=0$ if and only if $v=0$

Comment: In many cases the minimizing/maximizing procedure helps to simplify the constraints. But without knowing the model it is hard to say, if it is the case here.

Comment: If you don't have any upper bound, you cannot derive a mixed-integer linear programming representable model. Are you sure there is no upper bound? In almost all cases, there are natural domain constraints (such as if $v$ represents the amount of money invested, an upper bound defined as the total amount of money in the world is probably a conservative bound)

Comment: @JohanLöfberg If I had an upper bound, can I get rid of the strict inequality in 2)? Also I would be very interested in a sketch of a proof of your claim

Comment: If you would like to have a strict inequality in a MILP representation, you would have to replace it with $\leq 1-\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small for you, while large enough to make any sense in a numerical solver.

Comment: See for instance Constraint Qualification Failure in Second-Order Cone
Formulations of Unbounded Disjunctions by Hijazia & Libert and references there